# PHP formatting of positive and negative floating point numbers with leading zeros

Tags: php, floating-point, printf, number-formatting, negative-number

Scenario:
To trim leading zeros from positive and negative floating point numbers

Input:

```
000.123
00.123
01.123
-001.123
-00.123
-040.123
```

Desired output:

```
0.123
0.123
1.123
-1.123
-0.123
-40.123
```

Question:
Is there an inbuilt function which will make this specific formatting easier and more efficient than running each number through combinations of `substr()`, `strpos()`, `explode()` and `if` statements?

Comment: Please show us what you currently have, so we see at least you tried something and don't just ask us to write your code (BTW: A cast to float would do it: `echo (float)$str;`)

Comment: @Rizier123 I have tried many combinations of `substr()`, `strpos()`, `explode()` and `if` statements. Too many to list.

Comment: Try this: `echo sprintf("%01.3lf", $number);` or even simpler: `echo (float) $number;` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: @Rizier123 typecasting to float does the trick! Thankyou. Please post as an answer.

Comment: Done! Glade that i could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your numbers are saved as a string, so in order to get your output you just simple cast them to a `float` or `double` like this:

```
echo (float) $number;
```

For more information about casting see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it as `float`

Like this example:

```
<?php
$number = '-000.220';
echo (float)$number;
```

This way you remove all leading zeros, either being a positive or negative number